# Android: what does "it is not allowed to update UI from a non-ui thread" mean?

Tags: android, ui-thread

This works:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<....>{

    protected void onPostExecute(){
        // img is an ImageView
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Sorry guys, I think my question should be more accurate if I ask " why `img.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` is already run on UI thread. I thought it was updating a View in the UI from the `AsyncTask` thread.

Comment: You using both in onPost?

Comment: @nomnom show the full code no need to use runOnUithread it already invoked on ui thread

Comment: you can still create a method where you show the toast and invoke it on your onPostExecute()

Comment: @Manishika I think that is my question, why imv.setImageBitmap is already invoked on UI thread, I am confused. I think you overestimated me. I am really a rookie, please help me, thanks.

Comment: @nomnom pls post the full code of aysnctask to help you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 why img.setImageBitmap(bitmap) is already run on UI thread
```

Because you wrote it in `onPostExecute()` method of AsyncTask. In `AsyncTask`, the methods like `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` always run on your main UI thread, while only doInBackground() runs on a separate thread...